# How to save big data using Natife FIle System Api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filesystems, chrome-app-developer-tool

I'm trying to save big blob data using ShowSaveFilePicker API but it gives security error.

with corresponding message

> VM6785:61 DOMException: Failed to execute 'showSaveFilePicker' on 'Window': Must be handling a user gesture to show a file picker.

Comment: I think these examples will help you understand how to work correctly with FS API. [FS API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/#create-a-new-file) and [How save file](https://web.dev/patterns/files/save-a-file/).